# How does the Phantom 3 4k UAV assign the coordinates/geotag to each photo?

Tags: gps, satellite, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, photos

I read that the Phantom 3 used to use a barometric reading but now it uses GPS. Does it take a new reading from the GPS/Glonass satellites every time it takes a photo or does it base every photo from the initial coordinate it established when it is turned on before flght? Furthermore, does it take the pitch, role, yaw into account when calculating the coordinate for the photos?

Answer (score 1):

In general geotags are provided for each photo from the nearest fix (in time). Generally receivers are configured to output at 1Hz.

Re-installing a barometer could improve the height coordinate as GNSS height is worse than the horizontal coordinates due to the Earth blocking halve of the vertical plane: [DOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilution_of_precision_(navigation)). You would need to use an [EXIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) editor to write the height info ([derived from pressure](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/kinetic/barfor.html)) to your photo's.

The coordinate itself does not require motion/orientation data. It is possible however to write this kind of data to the EXIF of the photo's. I would recommend to at least log the direction data as this can be used in **GIS symbology** to display the image direction.